# PHP phar install on FreeBSD (phar.so not found)

Tags: installation, composer-php, freebsd, php-extension, phar

Dedicated server -
FreeBSD 8.2 -
amd64 -
Apache/2.2.21 -
PHP/5.3.9

I am trying of install the dependency manager for php composer, but composer needs the extension "phar".

Try

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Get

```
The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar
```

In `php.ini` and `extensions.ini` `extension=phar.so` not found. Add line, but file search `phar.so` has not brought results.

`php -i` and `php -m` show extension phar not installed

Try

```
cd /usr/ports/archivers/php53-phar && make install clean
```

Get

```
php53-phar: No such file or directory
```

I think command `portsnap fetch update` delete old `/usr/ports/archivers/php53-phar` directory

Try

```
cd /usr/ports/archivers/php5-phar && make install clean
```

Get meny errors like

```
Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.php.mk", line 267: Malformed conditional (defined(_POSTMKINCLUDED) && ${USE_PHP:tl} != "yes") "/usr/ports/archivers/php5-phar/../../lang/php5/Makefile", line 208: if-less endif Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.php.mk", line 267: Malformed conditional (defined(_POSTMKINCLUDED) && ${USE_PHP:tl} != "yes") Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.sites.mk", line 1049: Malformed conditional (!empty(_PERL_CPAN_ID) && ${_PERL_CPAN_FLAG:tl} == "cpan") Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 2948: warning: Missing closing parenthesis for defined() Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 2948: Malformed conditional (((!defined(OPTIONS_DEFINE) && !defined(OPTIONS_SINGLE) && !defined(OPTIONS_MULTI))  && !defined(OPTIONS_GROUP) && !defined(OPTIONS_RADIO)  || defined(CONFIG_DONE_${PKGBASE:tu}) ||  defined(PACKAGE_BUILDING) || defined(BATCH))) "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 2950: if-less endif Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier '-'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4358: Need an operator Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4903: warning: Missing closing parenthesis for target() "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4903: warning: Missing closing parenthesis for target() Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

8 open conditionals:
                at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
               at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
              at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
             at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
            at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
           at line 5785 (evaluated to true)
          at line 4903 (evaluated to true)
         at line 4903 (evaluated to true) make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
```

This version for PHP 5.4?

**How do I install the phar extension on PHP 5.3.9?**

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/172-PHAR-and-FreeBSD.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3 isn't officially supported in FreeBSD ports anymore, as well as FreeBSD 8.x itself.

Your options are:

- Obtain ports tree for FreeBSD 8.x. `portsnap` won't do, use `svn` to
  checkout FreeBSD ports tree on right branch/revision.
- Compile phar from source. As this is just extension, it shouldn't be
  too hard.